# tinyMce addContent not working

Tags: javascript, tinymce, textarea

I have the following code. The setContent portion isn't working. If I do a view source, I can see that the info from $rowpost["blog"] is getting put into the page, just isn't being displayed for some reason.

```
<textarea name="txtBlog" id="txtBlog" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js?apiKey=3x7na4p57b2ukuixfz5ird4sgs0kqhpfwzxlg0vz0j4dv4bd"></script>
<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector:'textarea',
        menubar:false,
        plugins:[
            'advlist autolink link lists image charmap print preview anchor textcolor',
            'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
            'insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste code help'
        ],
        toolbar:'styleselect | undo redo | bold italic backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat | help'
    })
    tinymce.get("txtBlog").setContent('<?php echo $rowpost["blog"]; ?>');
</script>
```

Any ideas or suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks

**EDIT**

I changed the code to this, but when I refresh the page, it changes the textarea back to a regular textarea. It does, however, display the information from the database.

```
<textarea name="txtBlog" id="txtBlog" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js?apiKey=3x7na4p57b2ukuixfz5ird4sgs0kqhpfwzxlg0vz0j4dv4bd"></script>
<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector:'textarea',
        menubar:false,
        plugins:[
            'advlist autolink link lists image charmap print preview anchor textcolor',
            'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
            'insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste code help'
        ],
        toolbar:'styleselect | undo redo | bold italic backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat | help'
        setup: function (editor) {
            editor.on('init', function () {
                this.setContent("<?php echo $rowpost["blog"]; ?>");
            });
        }
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Have you checked the browser's console for errors?

Comment: And have you tried echoing your PHP into the textarea without the setContent call? E.g. `<textarea><?php echo $rowpost["blog"]; ?></textarea>`

Comment: No errors, and  loading the data into the textarea without the tinyMce displays the info.

Comment: Isn't that what you want?

Comment: When I say it changes back to a regular textarea, it gets rid of the tinyMCE bar at the top for editing the text. If I take out the setup: function portion, it displays the bar at the top.

Comment: Hmmm, that seems odd. Check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/w2hxu3kg/2/. I'm setting the content of the textarea and then running TinyMCE which creates the instance of TinyMCE with the text from the textarea

Comment: Following your example fixed it. Other examples said to load the script after loading the textarea, but moving it to before the textarea, and putting the php code into the textarea worked. Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load content into TinyMCE as a page loads you can use the setContent function to do that ... but you need to make sure that TinyMCE is initialized before you try to use `setContent()`.  In your example you call `init` and then immediately call `setContent()` without checking to see if the editor is loaded.

The best way to do what you want is to put the code to load the content into the configuration object for TinyMCE. For example:

```
tinymce.init({
  ...
  setup: function (editor) {
    editor.on('init', function () {
        this.setContent("<p>My new content</p>");
    });
  }
  ... 
});
```

The `init` function won't get called until the editor has finished initializing so you are sure that everything is ready before the `setContent()` code is called.

*Note:  Using the init ensures you can target that specific instance of TinyMCE via `this`. in case you have multiple editors on the page.  You don't need to use the `get()` API using this approach.*

Comment: You appear to have double quotes within double quotes in that code that inserts the content.  Try making the outer ones single quotes?